# Is there any significance to the "id_rsa" keyfile name for GitHub?

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

A lot of tutorials about working with SSH for GitHub assume the use of the default `id_rsa` file name for the keyfile.  Is there any particular significance to that specific file name, or any reason it should be used as opposed to something specific e.g. `github_rsa`?  I'll admit I'm pretty fuzzy around best practices in the area, and I haven't found anything in a web search that indicates *why* that particular name is used, or if there's any benefit to keeping it or using something different.

Answer (score 3):

The name `id_rsa` is simply the default filename used by SSH for RSA keys. If you run `ssh-keygen` and accept all the defaults, it will create the file `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

The `ssh` command will look for this file by default, so using the default name reduces the amount of additional configuration required to make things work.

You can certainly name it something else, and then configure ssh to use that key explicitly for github.

Comment: If you have multiple things that use SSH, would they typically all use the same file (e.g. `id_rsa`), or would you create one for each?

Comment: It really depends on your particular situation. For example, if you have multiple distinct GitHub accounts, you'll want a separate key for each account.

Comment: And each keyfile stores exactly one key?

Comment: That's correct. Your `authorized_keys` file can contain multiple (public) keys, but public and private key files can only contain a single key.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [larsks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68582400/1256452), a stock [ssh-keygen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) will create:

- `~/.ssh/identity` for version 1 RSA
- `~/.ssh/id_dsa` for version 2 DSA ([do not use this](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/112802/264003) as the support has gone away, plus, apparently, some SHA-1 issues)
- `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa` for elliptic-curve DSA ([do not use this one either](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/46781/264003) in case you have a bad implementation)

and so on.  The current recommendation is to use version 2 RSA with long keys (2048 bits or more) or Ed25519 (less widely supported).  The wide support for the modern RSA is what leads to assuming `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.